# Flutter FCM: How to logout a user when phone is terminated through FCM

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

so i am working a app that deals with user disabling user account, so if a user violate the rule of the app, i want to log out the user immediately or when next he lunch the app through `Puch notification`,

i was able to logout the user when user click on the Notification,

but i want when the user did not even click the notification and when the app is terminated how will i logout the user when he lunch the app

Comment: what are the parameters for auto login user?  are you strore the apiKey? if yes, then just clear it when receive Notification

Comment: no parameter, using firebase as the authentication flow @pmatatias